# Magento 2 email item list add product attributes

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, email, sales-order, transactional-mail

i want to add some product attribute to the ew order email .
I cloned file in template and trying to do changes as below but it is not working

```
<?php

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems */

/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item = $block->getItem();
$_order = $_item->getOrder();


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getId());

?>
<tr>
    <td class="item-info<?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?> has-extra<?php endif; ?>">
        <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>


<p class="product-name">Add New Attribute : <?php echo $product->getNewAttribute();?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is extend the **DefaultItems** block with a more enhanced block.

In your module's **Block/Order/Emaiil/Items/DefaultItems.php**:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Order\Email\Items;

class DefaultItems extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems
{
    public function getNewProductAttribute() {
        return $this->getItem()->getProduct()->getCustomAttribute('new_product_attribute');
    }
}
```

In your module's **view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_invoice_renderers.xml** (This depends on which email template you want to change):

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.invoice.renderers">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems" name="sales.email.order.invoice.renderers.default" as="default" template="Vendor_Module::email/items/invoice/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And lastly, in your module's **view/frontend/templates/email/items/invoice/default.phtml**:

```
...

<p class="product-name">Add New Attribute : <?= $block->getNewProductAttribute() ?></p>
```

Comment: hi @Jorge1o1 : it seems not working seems where i need to tell plugin to use "Block/Order/Emaiil/Items/DefaultItems.php"